# SKTools use only Navigation UI issues

Tags: android, skmaps

I'm using SKTools to provide to the user the UI **only** for the navigation (so I call the start navigation method from the library as documented in the example but I **don't** calculate the route from that library. But instead from other activity which calculates without any problem all the routes and sets one by his unique id from that activity, later I do a `startActivity()` and I do the `startNavigation()` from `SKToolsNavigationManager` and everything's ok like the UI show but the problem is with de data of the route.

`onUpdateNavigationState()` from `SKToolsLogicManager` is correctly called but I always recieve trash from the `sknavigationstate`, like for example, no speed, no advice, and the ID = -1.

Anyone can throw a little of help and let me discover why this doesn't work now for SKMaps 2.5 when it worked on previous versions?

Thank you.

Comment: It is even possible to calculate the route and set to the ```SKRouteManager.getInstance().setCurrentRouteByUniqueId(routeID)``` in one activity, start another activity and launch the navigation with the previous set route? Because I'm now thinking that the reason why I'm getting SKNavigationStates like: ```SKNavigationState [adviceID=-1, currentSpeed=8.48764990139376E-59, currentSpeedLimit=0.0, ...]``` is because the navigation is not ok, but on the other hand, is displayed on the map correctly... Any suggestions?

Comment: As for http://forum.skobbler.com/showthread.php/7170-Android-Can-t-get-navigation-informations?p=21166#post21166 the answer was: "I found out the issue, if the SKAdvisorSettings are not properly configured (like the path to the sources for the advices) you get that kind of error, It could be useful if SKAdvisorSettings throws some kind of error to let the developer know that something is wrong with the configuration."

Comment: Yeah! Thank you, that actually was my answer in your forums